# Multi-Media Book App for iPad - Obj-C or Corona Or Cocos2D?

Tags: objective-c, ipad, coronasdk

I am planning to build a BOOK APP (with text, images, animation, sound etc) for iPad. I started learning Obj-C But I came to know about frameworks like Corona & Cocos2D and Corona boasts to be promising for my scenario. I have no working experience with any of these but am willing to learn. Which one is better to start with for building a multi-media book app? XCode & Obj-C OR Corona OR Cocos2D and how would would be the learning curve?

Answer (score 1):

I can't speak for Corona, but Cocos2D is just an Obj-C library, so you'll still have to know a bit of Obj-C to get it going.

That said, I started with just Objective-C, then found Cocos2D which greatly improved my development speed, as all the groundwork is already implemented. Cocos2D has a much more managable learning curve than doing it all from scratch, and there are a number of great resources available ([cocos2d forums](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/forum/), [this blog](http://www.raywenderlich.com/tutorials), etc).

A quick Google search showed me that Corona has costs associated with it for distribution - cocos2d does not.

Comment: Thx badgerr. I will do some reading on cocos2d. I am ready to learn Obj-C but wanted to know is it better to stick to Native platform (Obj-C) or use one of the available frameworks...

Answer (score 0):

I'd have to say Corona SDK is perfect for making a book app as you described. The basis for this claim is that there have been iPad eBooks created using Corona which have made the top charts on the app store (See: http://blog.anscamobile.com/2010/11/rabbit-and-turtle-race-to-1-in-app-store-ebooks/ for a quick example).

Also, Chronicle Books (San Francisco based book publisher) has used Corona SDK to produce an eBook for the Nook platform:

http://www.barnesandnoble.com/w/animal-show-chronicle-books/1100618669

And several others I can't think of off the top of my head.

The reason why Corona is great is because books are about getting images, text, and interactivity on the screen, and with Corona, you can do each one of those things in just a few lines of code or less!

Also, with the full-power of OpenGL, you have near limitless possibilities when it comes to adding as much--or as little--interactivity to your book as you want. With Corona, you really do get to focus on the logic behind your book app, rather than all the technical details which are handled transparently for you in the background.

For more information on eBook and Corona, visit this page:
http://www.anscamobile.com/corona/switch/e-book-developers/